# CopyToAsync() dont' fill the memory stream

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, system, memorystream

i'm using xamarin.forms app and need to save file(it this situation pdf file). This is my scenario: I'm using media plugin to save images with camera and from that images with PdfDocument object i generate PDF file:

```
  PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();


            for (int i = 0; i < Images.Count(); i++)
            {
                PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

                PdfGraphics graphics = page.Graphics;

                  Stream imageStream = Images.ElementAt(i);
                PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(imageStream);

                page.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new PointF(40, 100));

            } 
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
              document.Save(stream);
            document.Close(true);


  String localPath =
                      Task.Run(() => DependencyService.Get<ISave>().SaveFile(stream, "test.pdf")).Result;
```

And everything is working fine, its generates me pdf document with pages stream is filled with bytes, and the problem is in this SaveFile:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Save))]
namespace PdfSave.Droid.Shared
{
    public class Save: ISave
    {
        private readonly string _rootDir = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "TestFolder");
        public async Task<string> SaveFile(Stream pdfStream, string fileName)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(_rootDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_rootDir);          
            var filePath = Path.Combine(_rootDir, fileName);
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await pdfStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            return filePath;
        }
}
```

the problem is in this line

```
await pdfStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
```

the memory stream is empty! . Anyone know what should might be the problem?

Comment: You are creating a new stream and it's empty. What are you expecting to happen? Do you mean the memoryStream is empty after CopyToAsync?

Comment: do you know how CopyToAsync work?

Comment: form pdfStream i fill to memoryStream

Comment: What about CopyTo? Did you try that? Also try removing the using as of now for testing, as using disposes the MemoryStream created. If I get to find anything I'll post here

Comment: i will try thank you

Comment: Debug and check if the `memoryStream`'s length is above 0. If above zero the Stream is not empty but the Position has to be reset. Please set Position of the new stream `memoryStream` to 0, after CopyToAsync() and check if the file write works.

Comment: Hmmm i will try, but its very interesting why should not fill this memory stream

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209830/discussion-between-nikhileshwar-and-razzzz).